# How to store intervals and lookup interval by value?

Tags: java

I have a list which have three objects suppose name it as data.

1. data[0] has 0-6
2. data[1] has 6-13
3. data[2] has 13-23

I have a method and it has two arguments one is `starttime` and another is `endtime`.
My requirement is if the input values are in between the first object then this method will return the first object. If the input values are in between the first two objects then the method should return the first two objects. How can I do this. Can any one tell me?

Comment: Stabbing query? Is there any requirement about efficiency?

Comment: yes.The searching should be performed efficiently.

Comment: *If I remember correctly*, Interval Tree will allow you to do this efficiently.

Comment: How many ranges are there? And can they overlap many times (more than twice)?

Answer (score 5):

**Assuming you do not have overlapping ranges and the ranges are continual** as in your example (otherwise you will need to implement something yourself):

You can use a [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) to store the start or the ranges with their value, for example

```
TreeMap<Int, Object> map = new TreeMap<Int, Object>();
map.put(0, obj1);
map.put(6, obj2);
map.put(13, obj3);
```

Then use [TreeMap.floorEntry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#floorEntry%28K%29) to get `the greatest key less than or equal to the given key`

then you get:

```
map.get(0); // obj1
map.get(3); // /obj2
nap.get(22); // obj3
```

You can add a check to see if the key is less than 0 or greater then 23 and don't check the map for those values.

For your problem, you can check both `starttime` and `endtime` and see if you get the same object.

Comment: It is an acceptable solution if the ranges forms a continual spectrum, or only overlapping on ends. If the ranges can overlap many times over, then it will be different story altogether.

Comment: I agree, wrote that based on his example.